# Wordpress Ajax call to external URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In a plugin in the admin part of my Wordpress site I need to add functionality which uses ajax and sends data to a remote url.

However, I need help on what is the right way for wordpress to write the ajax request.

At the moment I have:

```
$('#button').on("click", function (){
var search = $("#buttonText").val();
        $.ajax({
            //dataType: "json",
            type : 'GET',
            url: 'Examplesite.com/myscript.php',
            data: {"search":search},
            success: function (data)
            {
                alert(val(data));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On button click, an alert with the returned data from the remote script is displayed

I know wordpress has "**ajaxurl**" but can I use this for external url or it is not required?